# Recommend ways for passing configuration to modules

Tags: node.js, design-patterns

What's the recommended way for passing setting variables to node.js modules?
Currently I'm using the following design which needs to place require calls inside the module.exports function. This is done that way to avoid using `var config = require('./myConfig')` everywhere because the idea is to require config **only once** in the app entry point (aka app.js, server.js...)

```
// A module that needs configuration settings when required.

// Some requires here...
var sample_module1 = require('amodule');
var sample_module2 = require('another_module');


module.exports = function(config) {

var apiKey = config.apiKey; // Get api key from configuration.

// This require must be here because needs 'config' variable...
var apiCaller = require('../lib/api_caller.js')(apiKey);


// An exported function that also uses configuration settings.
exports.makeCall = function(callback) {

  // Get some settings from configuration.
  var text = config.welcomeText; 
  var appName = config.appName; 

  // Use apiCaller module...
  apiCaller.send(appName, text, function(e){
    if (e) { return callback(e); }
    return callback(null);
  });
}

...

return exports;
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a better alternative to use '../lib/api_caller.js' module (by refactoring it, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be using something like [nconf](https://github.com/flatiron/nconf) and rely on it to load the right files at the right time. Particularly in your case, I'd go by creating a `conf` folder in the root of your project with a `default.json` configuration file. You can then create a global `configuration.js` that leverages `nconf` and the newly created file:

```
var nconf = require("nconf")
  , path = require("path")
  , environment;

nconf.argv().env("_");

environment = nconf.get("NODE:ENV") || "development";

nconf.file("default", path.resolve("config/default.json"));

module.exports = nconf.get
```

From the other modules that require the some configuration, you can simply use:

```
var conf = require('configuration.js')
conf('NODE_ENV') // print NODE_ENV
```

But it sounds like it's very similar to what you DON't want. The other option is to use something like a constructor:

```
var ApiCaller = require('../lib/api_caller.js');
var apiCaller = new ApiCaller({ some: 'parameter' });
apiCaller.doSomething();
```

where the "class" `ApiCaller` looks like:

```
function ApiCaller(options){
  this.options = options;
}

Api.prototype.something = function(){
  this.options //my options
};
```